# Chrome extension : Functionality is not saved but Checkbox state is saved

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm newbie to both stack overflow and programming. I'm trying to create a chrome extension that blocks when visiting instagram. I've integrated a checkbox in the chrome popup. When I visit instagram website, then turn on the switch/checkbox from the popup, it'll updated into pandora.com. but after checking it once in popup. I want it to be blocked when visiting instagram in other tabs too. With my current code, I need to keep opening the popup and turning on so that i can block for every instagram tabs i visit. I used storage api in my code but only the state of the checkbox is saved but not its functionality.

Following is my popup.js code :

```
   document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
     var checkbox = document.querySelector("input[name=checkbox]");
     chrome.storage.local.get('enabled', function(result){
       if (result.enabled != null){
        checkbox.checked = result.enabled;
        console.log("Wae");
        }
       });
  

        checkbox.addEventListener("click", async() => {
       console.log(checkbox.checked);
        chrome.storage.local.set({'enabled': checkbox.checked}, function(){
           if(checkbox.checked){
          console.log("???");
            var currentURL;
            chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
            currentURL = (tabs[0].url).includes('instagram');
            if (currentURL == true) {
              console.log("bang bang bang");
              chrome.tabs.update({url: 'http://www.pandora.com/'});
            }
          });
        } else{
          console.log("checkbox is not checked")
        }
        
      console.log("confirmed");
       });
       });
       });
```

Comment: “*I want it to be blocked when visiting instagram in other tabs too.*” Can you explain why, then, you’ve elected to query the current browser tabs with the parameter `active: true`? Isn’t that counter to the requirement you’ve explained?

Comment: Use chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules to add/remove a new redirect rule.